# How can I return a class with generic?

Tags: c#

Here is the class:

```
public record ValueModel<T>where T:struct
{
    public T Value { get; init; } 
    public Boolean Result { get; init; }
}
```

And here is the method to return a ValueModel result:

```
public ValueModel<T> GetValue<T>(string key)
{
  ///some logic
  ///return a ValueModel;
}
```

As the method I code above, VS always reports error. It said T must be a non-nullable value type.

What's wrong with my code and how should I correct it?

Comment: Can you add `where T : struct` to `GetValue` somewhere, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of `ValueModel<T>` say that the generic type `T` must be a `struct` since you wrote `where T:struct` in your method definition. But the method `GetValue<T>` defines the generic type `T` without such restriction. This means that the return type of that method (`ValueModel<T>`) can be using a generic type, that is not a `struct`. That's a conflict the compiler is telling you about. `ValueModel<T>` say it must be a `struct`, but `GetValue<T>` say it doesn't have to.

Add the same "restriction" to the definition of `GetValue<T>` again like this:

```
public ValueModel<T> GetValue<T>(string key) where T:struct
{
    ///some logic
    ///return a ValueModel;
    return default;
}
```

This way the generic type `T` for `GetValue()` can only be a `struct`, which fits the restriction of the generic type `T` of `ValueModel<T>`.

Comment: All right, it works now!